# Have a context menu entry pass parameters to a windows service while it is running

Tags: wcf, windows-services, registry

I have a simple windows service called lets say "MyService", built using WCF that on start adds a registry entry to "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\Shell\{ContextMenuEntryName}" thus allowing for the right click menu anywhere in windows to have an entry named :  {ContextMenuEntryName}. The target executed on clicking this entry is another program e.g. "{Path}\serviceclient.exe %1". The "%1" gives me the path of the windows folder that that context menu has been invoked on. This program then takes that value and passes it to my service by creating a proxy of the service and invoking its method.

The WindowsService code for its OnStart method is as follows:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            
            if (_serviceHost != null)
            {
                _serviceHost.Close();
            }

            // Add registry entry for context menu option                             System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            string contextMenuCommandPath =
                Environment.CurrentDirectory.Substring(0, Environment.CurrentDirectory.IndexOf("MyService")) +
                "serviceclient\\bin\\Debug\\serviceclient.exe %1";
            _contextMenu.AddContextMenu(ContextMenuName, contextMenuCommandPath, "Folder");
            _contextMenu.AddContextMenu(ContextMenuName, contextMenuCommandPath, "*");

            // Create a ServiceHost for the CalculatorService type and 
            // provide the base address.
            _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

            // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
            // listening for messages.
            _serviceHost.Open();           
    }
```

The serviceclient.exe has the following code after adding a service reference named "MyService" to it:

```
        // Instantiate service proxy
        var myServiceClient = new MyService.MyServiceClient();
        // Execute monitor target based on path specified (or default).
        myServiceClient .Monitor(args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : string.Empty);
```

I would like to directly pass arguments to the Windows service itself when I click on the context menu entry instead of invoking another separate program that does the same thing.

Would it be possible to have the context menu entry directly pass information to a Windows Service in WCF while it is running?

Comment: @TrueWill: A Windows Service can host a WCF service. This appears to be what the op is using. The .exe he starts no doubt makes a call to the WCF service.

Comment: @John: Thanks for the clarifying that for TrueWill. Yes, WCF services can either be windows or web services. I have built the former. I have a WCF service wrapped in to a Windows service which is what I am trying to work with.

Comment: actually, a WCF service can be both. You can host a WCF service that uses an HTTP binding in a Windows service.

Comment: @John - thanks, didn't know that. I still don't see the point of integrating this with the Windows menu system. A tray icon app is a much more common way of controlling services.

Comment: @True: he's not trying to control the service. He's trying to pass information about the shell file system _to_ the service. It will be information about the chosen file or folder.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it on first glance, but it's a complicated subject. See [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yea, it definitely is a little tricky. The problem with a windows service is that it only accepts arguments on startup (in its OnStart() method). The only other way I can have the context menu entry talk to the service is the client program that creates a proxy of the WCF endpoint hosted inside my windows service and invokes its method and passes it the value passed to it by the context menu. I'd like for some way to have the windows service be self sufficient and not have to rely on a client program that acts as nothing more than a facilitator for message passing.

Comment: @Cranial: I don't see a way to do it without launching some kind of .exe, but maybe if you read the entire linked article, you'll see another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented a named pipe server inside your Windows service maybe you could send the file path data directly from the context menu command with something like:

```
echo %1 > \\.\pipe\{pipe-name}
```

However, you can't use the standard WCF NetNamedPipeBinding to implement the pipe server, because of [all the .NET-specific protocol requirements](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2010/11/04/talking-to-wcf-over-named-pipes-1-the-framing-protocol.aspx) baked into that binding, so you would need to do it either using the `System.IO.Pipes` classes, or write a custom WCF transport which just receives raw messages from the pipe.